# Bond symmetry in AX2 type triatomic molecules

Tags: molecular-structure

Will triatomic molecules of the AX2, AX2E, AX2E2 etc. (e.g. H2O or CO2), where the central molecule is bonded to two identical atoms, always have symmetric bond lengths in the ground state? If so, is there a simple explanation for why this symmetry should result in the lowest possible energy?

Comment: Now that's a good question.

Comment: The hydrogen atoms in carboxylic acid dimers are bound to two oxygen atoms, but the distances are different: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carboxylic_acid_dimers.png. For $\ce{[FHF]-}$, on the other hand, either symmetrical or slightly asymmetrical structures are reported, doi:10.3390/cryst6010003

Comment: @Karsten I don't think these are quite what the OP is asking about. In the dimers though the element is the same on each side of the H, oxygen, they are in chemically different environments so one would expect asymmetry, and in the bifluoride case, while I need to read it in detail, the asymmetric cases are in crystals where the asymmetric field due to the other ions could be expected to distort the ion. I think what is being asked is is there a case for an *isolated* AX2 type molecule where the two AX bonds are of different lengths.

Comment: If I understand you correctly to my understanding I would expect it to always be symmetric in an isolated triatomic molecule unless there is an underlying asymmetry such as orbital occupation, which immediately made me think of Jahn-Teller - CO2 has a doubly degenerate HOMO, does anybody know the geometry of isolated CO2+, BO2 or similar?

Comment: Damn - I forgot Jahn-Teller only applies to non-linear molecules so forget that idea for CO2, and I think the HOMOs for both H2O and SO2 are non-degenerate

Comment: @IanBush The carboxylic acid dimers are in the gas phase. It is not clear whether the chemical environment is different because you can write to equivalent Lewis structures just like you would for benzene.

Comment: @IanBush As for the hydrogen bifluoride anion, the crystal environment could be symmetric or asymmetric, depending on the type of crystal symmetry. If the environment is symmetric but the anion is not, you might get disorder. If the environment is asymmetric but the anion is symmetric (in the gas phase), you might see a distortion. In any case, it is possible to discuss the symmetry of the anion (and tackle the question computationally if experiments are confusing).

Answer (score -2):

When the central atom is bonded to equal atoms, the bonds does not need to be symmetrical. For example
NO2. The order of the bond is 1.5, and the order of the other bond is 2. So they are not the same longer.

Comment: You should read about resonance...